# Python Snowball Stemmer + RAKE: generates 'u's

Tags: python, rake, stemming

I am trying to get the keywords from a text file containing a text, and I'm stemming the text first. The code below works, but for some reason it generates the letter 'u' in front of the keyword list. E.g. this is what I get:

`[(u'keyword1', 5), (u'keyword2', 4)]`

And I'm not sure where the 'u' comes from.
Here is the code (after importing the packages):

```
stemmer = SnowballStemmer("english")
rake_object = rake.Rake("SmartStoplist.txt", 5, 3, 4)
s = open("test.txt", "r").read()
s = re.sub('[^a-zA-Z0-9-_*.]', ' ', s) # Remove special characters that might cause problems with stemming
words = s.split()
stemmed = [stemmer.stem(word) for word in words]
stemmed = ' '.join(stemmed)
keywords = rake_object.run(stemmed) # Perform RAKE on stemmed text
print(keywords)
```

Comment: It's just means that it's Unicode string , it's string type.

Comment: Ok thank you. I want to store the keywords to a text file but it also stores this 'u' in the text file. Do you know how I can just store the keywords in a text file? (so without the 'u', the brackets, and the scores)

Comment: This is python-2 right?

Comment: @vdvaxel: how do you store the strings in a textfile?

Comment: This is Python 2.7. I stored it using `f = open("keywords.txt", "w")
f.write(str(keywords))
f.close()`

Comment: Briefly, you need to use proper string formatting on the data in those tuples to get it to appear in the console or file without the leading `u`. Also, you may find this article helpful: [Pragmatic Unicode](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain.html), which was written by SO veteran Ned Batchelder.

Comment: But then you do not store the keywords individually, but the list...

Comment: @vdvaxel: perhaps you should consider *pickling* the object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means that it is Unicode string, stemmer returns this type of strings. It's been syntax since 2.0, in Pythons 2.x. To get more information, read [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html#unicode-strings). Don't worry about it.